# Java, will volatile also guarantee visibility?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class Stuff {
  private final Timer timer = new Timer(true);
  public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 1500;
  private volatile int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;


  public void doStuff(OtherStuff) {
     ...
     timer.schedule(timeout, ...);
  }

  public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
     this.timeout = timeout;
  }

  public int getTimeout() {
    return timeout;
  }

}
```

Instances of this class is accessed from just 1 thread, except the timeout variable which can be altered from another class. In my case a JMX bean, which means one can alter the timeout during runtime from a management interface.

The doStuff() could be running 100's of times/second, while the setTimeout() could be run once a week - so the ordering between someone doing setTimeout() and someone doing doWork() is not important.

Is making `timeout` volatile sufficient for such a case ? Will the memory model guarantee that setting this from one thread to be visible to the `doStuff()` method ?

Another alternative that seems safe would simply be:

```
public class Stuff {
  private final Timer timer = new Timer(true);
  public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 1500;
  private int timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
  public void doStuff(OtherStuff) {
     ...
     timer.schedule(getTimeout(), ...);
  }

  public void synchronized setTimeout(int timeout) {
     this.timeout = timeout;
  }
   public int synchronized getTimeout() {
    return timeout;
  }
}
```

Which of these 2 approaches would be preferred ?

Answer (score 7):

From a visibility perspective, both approaches are equivalent. Any read on a volatile that happens subsequently to a write on that same volatile variable is guaranteed to see the write.

So if one thread writes `timeout = newValue;`, any other threads subsequently calling `timer.schedule(timeout)` is guaranteed to see `newValue`.

This guarantee is specified in the [JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.

I would simply use volatile as the guarantees it provides are sufficient and it clearly shows your intent.

Comment: There is actually no guarantee :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I was hoping you wouldn't come across this! Now we have a confused OP!

Comment: I couldn't help myself :) But basically, it is both correct and helpful to use "strong promise" instead of "guarantee". It may be more confusing to read that "subsequent" with the regular wall-clock time meaning because some things fail to make sense that way.

Comment: What I took home from the discussion was that no jvm would breach that promise as it would break too many programs. And I haven't found a way to summarise it without making it confusing... so I stick to the bottom (if simplified) line!

Comment: For curious users, [this is what Marko refers to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761552/guarantees-given-by-the-java-memory-model).

Comment: It's just that it is somewhat icky to interpret the JLS as if it does provide a guarantee. The guarantee given is that what the thread wrote before the write to the volatile is guaranteed to be visible to the reading thread---and that's the really important guarantee. Add to that the promise of timeliness---and you have it all correct and clearly explained.

Comment: Put it another way what would you recommend for the OP's specific use case?

Comment: Clearly, the advice in your answer is absolutely correct (I've upvoted it already). The issue is only with the argumentation which supports a correct conclusion by a not-quite-correct premise.

Answer (score 1):

Despite both the approaches of the example are equivalent I think (because of the generality of the question) it's worth to talk about this:

The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value of the volatile variable **itself**. If the question was "will volatile also guarantee visibility of the same volatile variable?". The answer is yes.

But there is no guarantee visibility of the (if there are) other variables that are used before the writing on this variable.

From [Full volatile Visibility Guarantee](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html).

Example:

> When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B
>   reads that same variable, the values of **ALL** variables that were
>   visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible
>   to B **AFTER** reading the volatile variable.