# How to implement an Array of volatile elements

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I'm attempting to port a Java application to Scala. One part of the Java application has an implementation called `AtomicDoubleBuffer` which uses an [`AtomicLongArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.html) under the hood - using the result of [`Double.longBitsToDouble(value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble-long-) to read from the double buffer and [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits-double-) to write to the buffer.

I've been looking around the net for Scala implementation that could be better and I landed on [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/453.html) which says that this code block

```
class VolatileDoubleArray(val length : Int){
  val array = new Array[Double](length);
  @volatile var marker = 0;
  def apply(i : Int) = {marker; array(i); }
  def update(i : Int, x : Double) { array(i) = x; marker = 0; }
}
```

should give me happens-before guarantees. But I'm a little confused at how possible this is. Why should a volatile marker on one variable determine that a previous non-volatile "operation" succeeds? My interpretation of the [JSL 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) suggests that updating elements of `array` in one thread does not guarantee that other threads will see that update. Am I missing something? Or am I confusing the whole happens-before thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation in your example is correct, and makes the **happen before** guarantees.

Becuse **write to volatile variable** makes **all things made before** by the **writing thread** visible to **all threads** that **first read this volatile variable**.

The volatile "marker" variable is the point of memory barrier in this case.

in your example code:
"

```
class VolatileDoubleArray(val length : Int){
  val array = new Array[Double](length);
  @volatile var marker = 0;
  def apply(i : Int) = {marker; array(i); }
  def update(i : Int, x : Double) { array(i) = x; marker = 0; }
}
```

"

when you write to the array in `update` you also write to volatile variable right after that using `marker=0;`,
and before any read in `apply` from array you first read the volatile variable by just the statement `marker;`.

This makes any writes to the array (even performed by different threads) visible to any reads (happens before guarantee, in this case after any `update` is complete, any thread performing `apply` will see it).

Comment: Hmm wasn't aware of that - any pointers would help. One question though, in that code snippet, isn't the compiler at any liberty of performing any optimisation given that `marker` is initialised with value `0` and is always set to the same value. I'm not sure but this looks like something the compiler could optimise out completely. Or is this illegal on a volatile variable?

Comment: No, compiler hasn't any liberty of performing any optimisation on volatile variables that could affect concurrent programming (like removing one, since the side-effect of read or write to volatile is making the memory barrier) nor the order of execution can be changed for them at runtime, that's exactly the purpose of volatile variables.

Comment: And for some pointers, I belive this is good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246007/java-memory-model-volatile-variables-and-happens-before

Comment: Thanks, [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) is another link that has cleared my confusion in addition to your help